# PHP переменная с кавычками внутри двойных кавычек

Tags: php, кавычки

Вот так должно быть `<offer id="935" available="true">`

вот кусок кода
`$yml = "<offer id='" . $py['product_id'] . "' available=\"true\">" . $this->eol;`

результат `<offer id='935' available="true">`
id в одинарных кавычках, а должно быть в двойных (

Comment: в html всё равно будут двойные. так какая разница какие они до вывода?

Comment: там xml на выходе

Comment: окей. у вас есть в коде пример с `available=\"true\"`. Почему вы не можете сделать точно также и с другим атрибутом?

Comment: он динамический в виде php переменной $py['product_id']

Comment: нет, вы вставляете переменную в атрибут....конкатенируя со строкой....но к кавычкам это не имеет никакого отношения

Comment: переменную можно вставить в строку так `{$py['product_id']}` вроде. без конкатенации

Comment: заменяете все `'` на `\"` и получается точно так же как с `\"true\"`.... а переменную `$py['product_id']`  не трогать

Comment: прокатило `$yml = "<offer id=\"{$py['product_id']}\" available=\"true\">" . $this->eol;`

Comment: результат `<offer id="935" available="true">`

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно проэкранировать двойные кавычки, как вы сделали с `available=\"true\"`:

```php
$yml = "<offer id=\"" . $py['product_id'] . "\" available=\"true\">" . $this->eol;
```

Comment: да рабочий вариант ..

Comment: в случае конкатенации проще всю строку завернуть в одинарные, а не двойные,тогда экранировать не надо. В случаев двойных, проще вписать переменную прямо в строку, избежав конкатенации.

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле есть много вариантов для строки. Они все описаны в документации в разделе [строки](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php). Там описаны и варианты с HEREDOC/NOWDOC и с подстановкой переменных и с экранированием и различия одинарных кавычек от двойных и подстановка управляющих последовательностей в виде `\n \t` и т.д.

Я хотел было написать тут варианты решения, но подумал, что их будет очень много и проще будет прочитать именно раздел работы со строками, чем копировать 25 скроллов документации. Это намного полезнее